# Command not found - script writing putty error?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, putty

I'm super new to Bash scripting and I'm stuck. I'm supposed to write an `ls` command that will make the output different from the default.

I'm then supposed to put this `ls` command into a bash script called `newls.sh` that takes the name of the directory as its one and only argument and lists the contents of the directory in the new format.

My script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

ls -g -S -r -Q
```

When I do `./newls.sh` in puTTY it does exactly what it's supposed to do, but it does it on my files. I need it to be able to do it on a different directory, but when I try it gives me a `newls.sh: command not found` error.

I got this error by entering `newls.sh /cas/course/220/poems`

`/cas/course/220/poems` is the directory I need it to work on. I've tried everything. I've tried `bash -x newls.sh` but that didn't change anything. It's probably a really simple error.

Comment: Lia, you don't have to wait. It would be better to upvote and/or accept the answers you've already received to your previous questions. The answerers would be sure to appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

So here what i understand from your question:- you want to list the content of the directory.
I had used command line argument for listing the content:--

```
#!/bin/bash

ls -g -S -r -Q $1
```

The above script can list the content if the directory location is passed in as a argument.
(Tip:-- It would be nice if you post your error snippet for further debugging.)

Comment: it's still saying newls.sh command not found. that's the only error

Comment: Run with /bin/bash newls.sh

Comment: Better: make it executable (with `chmod +x newls.sh`), then run it with `./newls.sh`. That way it uses the shebang to determine what shell to use (as it should). BTW, you should also double-quote variable references, like `"$1"` -- without the quotes, you can get weird parsing if the variable contains whitespace or wildcards. Finally, you might want to use `"$@"` instead of `"$1"` so if more than one argument gets passed to the script, they *all* get passed to `ls`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson It is executable already, as op mentions _When I do `./newls.sh` in putty it does exactly what it's supposed to do_ . She just needs to remember keep doing it. Also, `$1` should be in double quotes in case there is a space in the path, ie. `ls -g -S -r -Q "$1"`

Comment: @JamesBrown I just need to remember to keep doing what?

Comment: @nikhilesh_koshti when i tried that i got `ls: cannot access '': No such file or directory`

Comment: @Lia _The above script can list the content if the directory location is passed in as a argument_ Did you pass in the [wanted] directory location as [an] argument?

Comment: @JamesBrown the instructions show that we should be able to sort the contents of the directory by simply putting `newls.sh /cas/course/cisc220/poem`